# How to handle lazy loading of images on a large page?

Tags: javascript, html, lazy-loading

**The current approach that we are using to lazy-load images is:**

Server side templates render all image elements as:

```
<img
    src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7"
    data-src="http://static.com/img.jpg"
    style="display: none;"
/>
```

when `DOMContentLoaded` event is fired then JavaScript detects `<img />` elements that are in the viewport and replace `src` attribute value with the value of the `data-src`.

**Problem:**

Images on the front page do not appear until the entire DOM is loaded. Since this is a very large page (2MB HTML), it takes ~3-5 seconds until the `DOMContentLoaded` event is fired.

What I am looking for is a JavaScript solution that would enable me to load the first 100 images as soon as they become available for manipulation in the DOM.

Comment: It sounds from your comment: "JavaScript detects <img /> elements that are in the viewport and replace src attribute value with the value of the data-src" that you already have some javascript taking care of the images on this page. Why not just add a limit to load the first 100 images first?

Comment: Since you do not want lazy loading for the first 100 images why you do not change your server side code to use src same as data-src for the first 100 images?

Answer (score 0):

> What I am looking for is a JavaScript solution that would enable me to
>   load the first 100 images as soon as they become available for
>   manipulation in the DOM.

The solution that I have implemented is essentially this.

I needed a to abstract lazy loading script to enable re-indexing of existing images on the page. I would start by synchronously load this script before anything else in the document. From the moment that JavaScript can function, the script kicks off an interval when it attempts to find all image elements in the DOM and check if they are in the viewport. If elements are deemed in the viewport, it attempts to modify the image element (`data-src` to `src`). This interval continues until `DOMContentLoaded` is fired.

In terms of code, it looks like this:

```
const LazyImageLoader = require('./LazyImageLoader');
const domReady = require('domready');

/**
 * The reason for using setTimeout instead of setInterval
 * is to not re-run revalidate more often than the body
 * of the function can be evaluated.
 */
const createIntervalIterator = (callback, interval) => {
  let currentTimeout;

  const control = {};

  const iterator = () => {
    const startTime = new Date().getTime();

    callback();

    const evaluationTime = new Date().getTime() - startTime;

    const delayNextIteration = interval - evaluationTime;

    currentTimeout = setTimeout(iterator, delayNextIteration);
  };

  iterator();

  return () => {
    clearTimeout(currentTimeout);
  };
};

const iterationIntervalTime = 100;

const lazyImageLoader = new LazyImageLoader({
  offset: 100,
  selector: 'img[data-src]',
});

/**
 * Revalidation ensures that all images are in LazyImageLoader index.
 */
const revalidate = () => {
    lazyImageLoader.revalidate();
};

const cancelInterval = createIntervalIterator(() => {
  revalidate();
}, iterationIntervalTime);

domReady(() => {
  if (cancelInterval) {
    cancelInterval();
  }

  // Revalidate after domReady in case any images have been added
  // to the DOM after the last `revalidate` invocation.
  revalidate();
});
```